# Apache user can't play audio

Tags: sound, apache2

I have a shell script 'vlc.sh' that plays a video using vlc:

```
#!/bin/bash
vlc /home/sparky/sample.mp4
```

When I run this script from my login, I get audio + video.

When I call this script from the Apache user (via php), I get only video. 
 The Apache error log complains about audio:

```
[0x96053ec] pulse audio output error: cannot connect to server: Connection refused
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4184:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: 
No such file or directory
oss audio output error: cannot open audio device (/dev/dsp)
```

I've tried adding the apache user to the audio, pulse, pulse-access, and admin groups. But I've have had no luck. I'm running xubuntu 11.10. What should I try next?

Comment: Looks like there is quite a bit more to this than just setting up permissions. I found this: [link](http://www.microdevsys.com/WordPress/2010/07/12/vlc-videolan-video-player-failed-to-connect-to-the-d-bus-session-daemon-bindbus-launch-terminated-abnormally-with-the-following-error-no-protocol-specified/)  --Looks like a good guide to solving this problem:

Comment: If you have solved your problem, consider adding it as an answer and marking it, or if inappropriate, closing/deleting?

Answer (score 2):

*The answer was provided from a [link](http://www.microdevsys.com/WordPress/2010/07/12/vlc-videolan-video-player-failed-to-connect-to-the-d-bus-session-daemon-bindbus-launch-terminated-abnormally-with-the-following-error-no-protocol-specified/) mentioned by the OP in a comment. The following is an excerpt from it:*

> Turns out that I needed to edit the /etc/group file and add videouser
>   user to the audio user group of users who are allowed to have audio
>   while the root login is in session.  The line should like like this:
>
> ```
> # cat /etc/group|egrep -i "audio|pulse"
> audio:x:63:videouser,root
> pulse:x:474:videouser,root
> pulse-access:x:473:videouser,root
> ```
>
> after editing from:
>
> ```
> # cat /etc/group|egrep -i "audio|pulse"
> audio:x:63:
> pulse:x:474:
> pulse-access:x:473:
> ```
>
> and sure enough, there was sound.  However, the pulseaudio still
>   showed the error.  Appears a reboot is in order.